# Prevent duplicate value in gridcontrol devexpress using data table

Tags: c#, datatable, devexpress, gridcontrol

Fill `txtName`, `txtAddress` and press `btnSubmit` will give and add value to `GridControl` DevExpress.

This the codes:

```
DataTable dt;

private void XtraForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("NAME");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ADDRESS");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = txtName.Text;
    dr1[1] = txtAddress.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

The codes above worked properly.

How can I prevent duplicate value when data exist in `GridControl`? I want to get alert / message box that showing me duplicate value after `btnSubmit` pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find the existed rows in your `DataTable`. If there are no rows, then you can add new row, else you can show the message.
Here is example:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string address = txtAddress.Text;

    var rows = dt.Select(string.Format("NAME = '{0}' AND ADDRESS = '{1}'", name, address));

    if (rows.Length == 0)
    {
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = name;
        dr1[1] = address;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
    }    
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Some message.");        
}
```